Change in data distribution after applying scale() in R
I have a question about changes in distribution after applying scale() in R. If my whole procedure is false, I will happily welcome recommendations, corrections, suggestions.
As I tried constructing a LMM with lmer(), I ran into convergence issues due to data being on varying scales. I am predicting proportion of specific temporal orientation of thoughts (0 - 1.00) with hours since waking up (treated as continuous variable; 0-17 h since waking up), attentional demands (0-6) and score of a specific questionnaire (cumulative score 16-86).
According to my (limited) knowledge, scaling the data should not significantly change the distribution of the data. Accordingly, after scaling variables "attentional demands" and "questionnaire score" maintained distribution of the raw data. However in the case of hours since waking up, there was a (slight) change in distribution.
Raw distribution:

Distribution after scaling:

Why am I observing these changes in the distribution? I am happy to read into any existing answer on this forum or some literature as I cannot find an answer in the resources I am familiar with.

I am optimistic on your behalf that you're seeing artefacts at bin boundaries in your histograms. A better check would just be to plot your two versions as two axes on a scatter plot.  (Please don't assume that we know what scale() does exactly in R. Many of us are not R users at all, and even experienced R users can't know about every function.)

As your numbers really aren't very big or very small, my guess would be that convergence problems arise for quite different reasons unrelated to scaling.

Thank you! Scatter plot was indeed much more informative and as you suggested the apparent differences observed on hist were because of bin boundaries. I apologise for the assumptions about R and it's functions - my bias as I only look into posts about R on this forum.

Why don't you post what you found as an answer to your question, with code and a brief explanation? It's OK to answer your own question on this site, and that will help others who might come here with a similar problem. Also, I've learned to avoid using histograms in favor of density plots (you can think of them as smoothed histograms), as they don't have the artifacts due to the edges between bins.

@EdM Indeed about histograms, but density plots may have their own artefacts, as in some functions (in R and elsewhere) whenever some probability mass is smoothed beyond hard limits such as $[0, 1]$  and then omitted from the plot -- which is sometimes trivial but not always. There are known fixes, but they seem rarely implemented.

Worth noting that it's actually impossible for the those histograms to come out looking identical as generated - they don't even split the domain into the same number of bins, there cannot be a 1:1 correspondence between the bins on each plot.

@NuclearHoagie Well spotted.

Thanks for showing those results. Now, to keep things organized on this site and to let others know that you have found an answer, please take what you have added to the end of your question and paste it instead into the space for "Your Answer" on this page.

My apologies, still figuring out the whole posting protocol on this site. Thank you for all the comments!


You should note in your question what scale does by default (assuming you didn't change anything from the default) - it internally standardizes its argument (subtracts sample mean and divides by sample sd).  $:$ 2. It's important to note that while (for a fixed set of data), the shape of the empirical distribution of that data is unchanged (just its scale and location), the shape of the underlying sampling distribution is impacted by internal standardization, but not by external standardization.


What I thought are changes in the distribution were in fact artefacts at bin boundaries. As suggested, I tried scatter plotting my raw and scaled variable (plot(final_dataset_scaled$relative_sample_time_int, final_dataset_scaled$rel_time_scaled))
and additionally plotted density plots
(plot(density(final_dataset_scaled$relative_sample_time_int)) and plot(density(final_dataset_scaled$rel_time_scaled))).
Plots suggested that the distribution of the data after standardisation using scale() was in fact (of course...) maintained.


Thanks for posting this. (+1) As Nick Cox pointed out in a comment on the question, if your data have hard limits at the extremes (as it seems that yours might), there will still be some artifacts at the edges of the density plots, as the plot smooths out values into regions that might not be theoretically possible. Keep that in mind as you interpret the plots. For this type of comparison it doesn't really matter, as it shows that the scaling didn't do anything to affect the shape of the distribution.

As your data are discrete in practice -- originally the integers 0(1)16, it seems -- I would go further and say that the density estimate doesn't help at all. You can check that the histogram is unchanged by plotting a spike version of the histogram with the frequency for every distinct value, before and after scaling.  A separate guess is that scaling here may be just (value $-$ mean) / SD.
